# How to terminate databricks cluster from notebook?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to terminate azure databricks cluster from notebook level. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Can you give more details on your use case, please?

If you use the JOB cluster, it will be terminated as soon as your JOB is completed.

Comment: I have few databricks notebooks linked to datafactory. This notebooks uses common libraries. I wanted to start a cluster with these libraries, than run all notebooks and terminate it asap. I know I can set 10mins terminate, but is there a way to kill it instantly?

Comment: use cluster stop rest APIs for that. But really, you shouldn't use existing cluster, and instead create new cluster with all libraries attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ganesh Chandrasekaran in comments. You can choose Job cluster for your requirement.

Job clusters terminate when your job ends, reducing resource usage and cost.  The cluster is not terminated when idle but terminates only after all tasks using it have completed. If a shared job cluster fails or is terminated before all tasks have finished, a new cluster is created.

A cluster scoped to a single task is created and started when the task starts and terminates when the task is completed. In production, Databricks recommends using new shared or task scoped clusters so that each job or task runs in a fully isolated environment.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs#choose-the-correct-cluster-type-for-your-job

Comment: Job clusters can't be used in all circumstances, for example connecting via ODBC. I have the same problem, but cannot use a Job